# How to copy files from shared directory in multiple Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

In my application, I have 5 docker containers and each container starts from images that builds from Dockerfile. Following is the structure:

```
-projectdir
  -docker
    -application1
      -Dockerfile
      -script.sh
    -application2
      -Dockerfile
      -script.sh
    -application3
      -Dockerfile
    -application4
      -Dockerfile
      -script.sh
    -application5
      -Dockerfile
```

script.sh is copied in the Dockerfile in application 1,2&4. The problem is I have to put the same script.sh in each application directory. Is there any way to use shared folder that contain single script.sh and copy from that? I am using docker-compose to build and run the containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a container dedicated to keep your script in a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volume-driver) (as a [data volume container](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/))

```
scripts:
  volumes:
    - /path/to/scripts
application1:
  volumes_from:
    - scripts
application2:
  volumes_from:
    - scripts
```

The `/path/to/scripts` folder will be shared in each application.
The `scripts` Dockerfile should create `/path/to/scripts` and COPY the `script.sh` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used data volume container to store postgresql data. It seems to me overwork to use another data container to store script. Do you think it is best approach?. @adrian-mouat suggested another solution.

Comment: @frodooooo39 yes, or you can store your script in the first data volume container if you want. But it (data volume container) helps identifying what is shared. And it is portable (not tied to the host, like a regular mount would)

Comment: @frodooooo39 FYI: storing shared data in a container is not overhead, because data volume container do not need to be running, it only needs to exist.

Comment: @Dmytro true. You can simply `docker create` a data volume container (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29762465/6309). You don't have to run it ever.

Comment: Is this approach suitable if the shared script is only needed at build time?

Comment: @BurhanAli not really: at build time, you need to copy your script in the docker build context t COPY, RUN and RUN rm within the Dockerfile.

Comment: @shriek I have edited the answer to reflect the syntax now described in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volume-driver

Answer (score 3):

Since Docker 1.5, you can specify a path within the build context for the Dockerfile. So the following works:

```
-projectdir
  -docker
    -script.sh
    -application1
      -Dockerfile  
    -application2
      -Dockerfile
    ...
```

You can build with:

```
$ cd docker
$ docker build -f application1/Dockerfile .
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this with Compose yet, so you may have to use a separate script to build and tag your images which you can then use in Compose.

Comment: Can't you do it wit docker-compose by specifying `dockerfile: application1/Dockerfile`?