# How can I understand the role of "/bin/true" command in "docker run ..." command?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am following this [document](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/genezys/gitlab/) to install `gitlab docker image`, and get confused with the command:

```
docker run --name gitlab_data genezys/gitlab:7.5.2 /bin/true
```

I know "`/bin/true`" command just returns a success status code, but how can I understand the role of `/bin/true` in this `docker run ...` command?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Running and thus creating a new container even if it terminates still keeps the resulting container image and metadata lying around which can still be linked to.

So when you run `docker run ... /bin/true` you are essentially creating a new container for storage purposes and running the simplest thing you can.

In Docker 1.5 was introduced the `docker create` command so I believe you can now "create" containers without confusingly running something like `/bin/true`

See: [docker create](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#create)

This is new method of managing data volume containers is also clearly documented in the section [Creating and mounting a Data Volume Container](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)

Comment: The example in "Creating and mounting a Data Volume Container" is still using `/bin/true`.