# What is the right way to add data to an existing named volume in Docker?

Tags: docker

I was using Docker in the old way, with a volume container:

```
docker run -d --name jenkins-data jenkins:tag echo "data-only container for Jenkins"
```

But now I changed to the new way by creating a named volume:

```
 docker volume create --name my-jenkins-volume
```

I bound this new volume to a new Jenkins container.
The only thing I've left is a folder in which I have the `/var/jenkins_home` of my previous jenkins container. (by using `docker cp`)
Now I want to fill my new named volume with the content of that folder.

Can I just copy the content of that folder to `/var/lib/jenkins/volume/my-jenkins-volume/_data`?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You *can* certainly copy data directly into `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-jenkins-volume/_data`, but by doing this you are:

- Relying on physical access to the docker host.  This technique won't work if you're interacting with a remote docker api.
- Relying on a particular aspect of the volume implementation would could change in the future, breaking any processes you have that rely on it.

I think you are better off relying on things you can accomplish using the docker api, via the command line client.  The easiest solution is probably just to use a helper container, something like:

```
docker run -v my-jenkins-volume:/data --name helper busybox true
docker cp . helper:/data
docker rm helper
```

Comment: Regarding your second bullet, you can run `docker volume inspect my-jenkins-volume  --format '{{.Mountpoint}}'` to get it's physical location programmatically.  Still doesn't feel like a great idea though.

Comment: This helper container never needs to actually run.  It would be sufficient to simply create it, then run `docker cp` and then remove it.

Comment: You can't exec into that container to see the results or modify the files manually.

Comment: Note that listing `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-jenkins-volume/_data` when using [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) doesn't work because files are stored inside the [xhyve virtual machine](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve). See https://forums.docker.com/t/var-lib-docker-does-not-exist-on-host/18314

Comment: What does 'true'  do in the run statement above?

Comment: True is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762231/how-can-i-understand-the-role-of-bin-true-command-in-docker-run-command

Comment: @Alex How would that work? `docker create` instead of `docker run`?

Comment: @DavidMoles, yes, `docker create` instead of `docker run`

Answer (score 63):

You don't need to start some container to add data to already existing named volume, just create a container and copy data there:

```
docker container create --name temp -v my-jenkins-volume:/data busybox
docker cp . temp:/data
docker rm temp
```

Comment: Provided that busybox's contents are not really needed; you can do this with `hello-world` and it also works. `busybox` is 1.22MB. Instead `hello-world` is 13.3kB. The question is: The same way we can do a Dockerfile FROM scratch, could we do a "docker container create" with "nothing" as the image as we only want to just "mount" the volume and never start the container?

Comment: +1 for this solution over the top voted but the correct syntax for `docker cp` is `docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH`

Comment: @MarcoDufal that's one of the syntaxes, but also `docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH`.

Comment: @XaviMontero See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511611/1065654) for a solution that uses a Docker Image of size 0B. It is similar to this answer, but a little bit more complex, since my used image is build locally. This answer is simple and straight to the point. Thanks Dmytro Melnychuk

Comment: Good solution!! I like it!

Answer (score 46):

You can reduce the accepted answer to one line using, e.g.

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/src -v my-jenkins-volume:/data busybox cp -r /src /data
```

Comment: im wondering if the transient nature of /tmp may pose a risk of the container possibly deleting your data before cp completes? http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES

Comment: The link doesn't really clarify the lifetime of files in /tmp.  I states:
  
  "Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are preserved between invocations of the program."

which implies that the files would survive, but that's a guarantee.

The -v option for docker will create a directory in the container if is doesn't exist, so changing /tmp/src to /src will work if you are worried about this potential race condition.  I'll edit the answer to reflect this, since there is no downside.

Comment: doesn't the `-v \`pwd\`:/src` imply that the command is running on the host?  (How can the host map `pwd` if it's a different machine, for example?  -- it can't.) If the docker command isn't running on the host this doesn't work.  I believe that's why we have docker cp.  This seems like it is not "the way" for docker -- it's just a special case that works only when the docker command is running on the host.  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right.  `pwd` must resolve to a file on the host machine.  From docker's mount documentation:  "In the case of bind mounts, the first field is the path to the file or directory on the host machine."

Comment: Therefore, this does not work to copy *your* local files into the container *if* in a remote host, as you are mounting `pwd` which does not even need to exist in the remote host. Instead the solution by Dmytro Melnychuk (create+cp+rm) does copy the local ones into the container no matter where it is running.

Answer (score 9):

You can add this BASH function to your `.bashrc` to copy files to a existing Docker volume without running a container

```bash
# Usage: copy-to-docker-volume SRC_PATH DEST_VOLUME_NAME [DEST_PATH]
copy-to-docker-volume() {
  SRC_PATH=$1
  DEST_VOLUME_NAME=$2
  DEST_PATH="${3:-}"
  # create smallest Docker image possible
  echo -e 'FROM scratch\nLABEL empty=""' | docker build -t empty -
  # create temporary container to be able to mount volume
  CONTAINER_ID=$(docker container create -v "${DEST_VOLUME_NAME}":/data empty cmd)
  # copy files to volume
  docker cp "${SRC_PATH}" "${CONTAINER_ID}":"/data/${DEST_PATH}"
  # remove temporary container
  docker rm "${CONTAINER_ID}"
}
```

**Example**

```bash
# create volume as destination
docker volume create my-volume
# create directory to copy
mkdir my-dir
echo "hello file1" > my-dir/my-file-1
# copy directory to volume
copy-to-docker-volume my-dir my-volume
# list directory on volume
docker run --rm -it -v my-volume:/data busybox ls -la /data/my-dir
# show file content on volume
docker run --rm -it -v my-volume:/data busybox cat /data/my-dir/my-file-1

# create another file to copy
echo "hello file2" > my-file-2
# copy file to directory on volume
copy-to-docker-volume my-file-2 my-volume my-dir
# list (updated) directory on volume
docker run --rm -it -v my-volume:/data busybox ls -la /data/my-dir
# check volume content
docker run --rm -it -v my-volume:/data busybox cat /data/my-dir/my-file-2
```

Comment: This is great. Always felt weird to me that there wasn't a way to do this without busybox or alpine. Granted it is more commands, but doesn't download/spinup unnecessary resources

Comment: Great solution! But i think there is an error in the script function: my-volume should be $DEST_VOLUME_NAME

Answer (score 8):

Here are steps for copying contents of **~/data** to docker volume named **my-vol**

Step 1. Attach the volume to a "temporary" container. For that run in terminal this command :

`docker run --rm -it --name alpine --mount type=volume,source=my-vol,target=/data alpine`

Step 2. Copy contents of **~/data** into **my-vol** . For that run this commands in new terminal window :

`cd ~/data
docker cp . alpine:/data`

This will copy contents of **~/data** into **my-vol** volume. After copy exit the temporary container.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to create a docker and you can access as privileged user to , simply do (on Linux systems):

```
docker volume create my_named_volume
sudo cp -p . /var/lib/docker/volumes/my_named_volume/_data/
```

Furthermore, it also allows you to access data in docker runtime or also with docker containers stopped.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to create a temp helper container on windows docker desktop (backed by wsl2) then
copy the files to below location

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\my-volume\_data
```

here **my-volume** is the name of your named volume. browse the above path from address bar in your file explorer. This is a internal network created by wsl in windows.

[image]

Note: it might be better to use docker API like mentioned by [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469637/6563567), but I have not faced any issues on windows.

Similarly on linux files can be copied to

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-volume/_data/
```