# "docker container create" with "nothing" inside. Ie: An empty / void / null / scratch container

Tags: docker, docker-volume, minimum-size, scratch-file

It might be helpful to create a container that has nothing. Nothing means nothing.

## Use case

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683656/1315009 a container is created **without ever starting it** just to instantiate a volume and copy contents into the volume. Then the container is removed.

The example instantiates a `busybox`. Nevertheless the `busybox` contents are never used. So I tested it with the `hello-world` and it works as well, thus reducing from 1.22MB to 13.3kB.

At the time being, pulling "scratch" fails:

```
$ docker pull scratch
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: 'scratch' is a reserved name
```

## So... Question

How can I create a container with an image that has "nothing" inside?

I mean similar to `docker create hello-world` but without the `hello-world` binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired on @BMitch's answer, the solution is that the `Dockerfile` can not only contain the `FROM` sentence.

It compiles, but fails when doing a `docker create`, the engine complains because it does not have a command even if it's a create and not a run.

The complete Dockerfile is this one:

```
FROM scratch
CMD ""
```

You can build it (in my case I named the image `xavi-scratch`) and then see the image is 0 bytes of data:

```
$ docker image ls | grep xavi-scratch
xavi-scratch    latest    bee1419a6d83    N/A    0B
```

[image: image contains 0 bytes of data]

I then create a container without running it:

```
docker create -v ${PWD}/whatever-dir:/data --name test-scratch xavi-scratch
```

There's a full session here testing it serves the purpose:

1. Setup 2 empty dirs `a` and `b` and create one file in `a`.
2. Check `b` is empty
3. Create this container from the empty image, mounting `b`.
4. Copy the file from `a` into the container
5. Check `b` contains the file copied via the container.

[image: Test]

Answer (score 1):

A container is defined from an image and includes the command to run inside the container. A container that is just `scratch` has no commands to run and is therefore not a properly defined container. You can build an image that is nothing more than:

```
FROM scratch
```

However, you will quickly run out of things to do with the resulting image. If you need to manage a named volume, that volume will be attached to a container, and that container will use an image, so it's easiest to use that image directly.

Comment: The thing is we just want team-A to "prepare" some volumes with pre-filled read-only data, so when team-B runs their containers, they have the data there. Team-A does not have access to the images of Team-B. We do not want to pollute the host file-system. So the best way is to "prepare" volumes the same way anyone could prepare "hard disks with info" without having the final PC on which the disk will be consumed. This is why we want "a mechanism" to pre-fill volumes.

Comment: About not having a command, as I told in the question, that's the point: It'll be a container that will **never** surpass the state of `created` and will never start running. Do I need keys of a door that will never open? Same way: Do I need an ENTRYPOINT or CMD for an image that will be never run, just created but not run?

Comment: On the other hand you state "You can build an image that is nothing more than FROM scratch" and the sentence is not correct: If you do that, the builder says: "No image was generated. Is your Dockerfile empty?" This is the reason for the question: What's the "bare minimum" image that is creatable? Why "scratch" created a layer in older versions of docker and does not create a layer in newer versions?

Comment: @XaviMontero I had only tested with buildkit, which does create a scratch image. You could put a label in the image to avoid this error in the classic builder. But overall, this feels like a premature optimization. You could create an image with the volume initialization steps that may be a few megs, and then delete that image when done. You're already downloading lots of other files just to install the docker engine.