# MySql tables are not showing in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a local mysql database with some tables populated but when I try to mount it to a volume and access it through a container, I cannot. I'm able to use the database but no tables show up.

Here is my docker-compose.yml.

```
 db:
   image: mysql
   container_name: db1
   volumes:
     - practice-vol:/var/lib/mysql
   environment:
     MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
     MYSQL_DATABASE: test
     MYSQL_USER: docker
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
   # ports:
   #   - 3307:3306
     
 practice:
   image: practiceservice
   container_name: practice1
   ports:
     - 8081:8081

volumes:
 practice-vol:
     external: true
```

I'm running these command

```
me@me-laptop:~/Docker$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
4ebb2d5a0958   mysql             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   30 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp      db1
e8a2470fbddd   practiceservice   "java -jar /app.jar"     28 minutes ago   Up 9 seconds   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   practice1
me@me-laptop:~/Docker$ docker exec -it 4eb bash
bash-4.4# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.1.0 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

It should have two tables in it called "BLAHBLAH" and "new_table"
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I don't understand why it would see the database but not the tables

Comment: How did you create and populate the `practice-vol` volume?

Comment: I just ran "docker volume create practice-vol" then "docker compose build" "docker compose up". I was under the impression the "volumes:
     - practice-vol:/var/lib/mysql" part of the compose would link my local data with the volume. Am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: I think so. Where is this _"local data"_ you keep mentioning? Just because you've created a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) doesn't mean it will have anything on it.

Comment: @Phil the local data is here /var/lib/mysql. I created a database called "test" and created the tables BLAHBLAH" and "new_table" in "test' using MySQL workbench

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql` on the host and `/var/lib/mysql` on the container are completely different things. As far as I can tell, the data on your host has not been populated into the volume you created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the right way to add data to an existing named volume in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468788/what-is-the-right-way-to-add-data-to-an-existing-named-volume-in-docker)