# Best way to initialize named volume from Docker image/container

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to persist the `/home` (and/or the `/root`) folder in Docker with a named volume. What's the best way to initialize such named volume, with the content from the Docker image?

This question different from [What is the right way to add data to an existing named volume in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468788/what-is-the-right-way-to-add-data-to-an-existing-named-volume-in-docker) in that, it asked about copying files *from host* to named volume, whereas I'm asking to copy files *from Docker image/container* to named volume.

The problem that needs to overcome in this questions are:

- When I start with `docker run -v myhome:/home`, I do see files under `/home` in the container.
- However, those files are from the Docker images, not Docker named volume, i.e. the files from the Docker images are not copied into Docker named volume
- The problem with that is, when I commit my Docker image after further manual customization, the `/home` folder will be completely empty in the container I picked up via `docker start -ai mycontainer`.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best approach is to store the data somewhere outside the container, for example in a separate database container or using network-accessible storage, maybe a MinIO container or similar.  Delete the volume entirely.

Even if you can't rearrange your application to avoid local storage, do not mount a volume over the image content.  Like all kinds of Unix mounts, a Docker volume mount will hide what's in the image and replace it with the mounted host directory or named volume.

Instead, when the image starts up, it needs to copy data from the static content in the application into the volume directory.  I'd generally use an entrypoint wrapper script for this, something like

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint.sh

# Copy data from the image into the data directory
cp -r /app/data/ /data/

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

In the image, you need to make sure the data directory exists, but it should be empty.  A good practice is to set up a non-root user in the image, and that user should have permissions on the directory; but the user does not need to reflect any specific host user (you don't want to rebuild the image just because the host user ID changes).  Remember that all properties of this directory, including its ownership and permissions, will be overwritten by the mount.

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM ...

# Create a non-root user
RUN adduser -r appuser

# Copy the application into the image, including its data directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN a language-specific build command

# Create the data directory
RUN mkdir /data && chown appuser /data
# VOLUME /data  # optional
ENV APP_DATA_DIR=/data

# Usual metadata to run the application
USER appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["my_app"]
```

Now if you just run the image

```bash
docker run my-image
```

it will work fine; the data directory exists.  But if you mount some storage into the container

```bash
docker run -v some-named-volume:/data my-image

docker run -u $(id -u) -v "$PWD/data:/data" my-image
```

regardless of the kind of storage it is, the entrypoint script will copy the image content into the storage.

As I've written it here, the entrypoint script will always overwrite whatever is in the storage whenever the container starts up.  If you want the script to do something else, you can change this; for example, you might `test -f` if specific files exist and `cp` them only if they're missing.  The general case of a three-way merge between old image content, new image content, and locally modified content is hard (consider how often `git rebase` forces you to do manual merges) and there isn't a generic solution for this.

---

Docker has one specific corner case, very specifically about Docker named volumes and very specifically about empty volumes, where content gets copied into volumes.  Do not use this functionality.  It doesn't work with Docker bind mounts, Kubernetes PersistentVolumeClaim or `emptyDir` storage, or any other kind of volume mount, and anything that does wind up in the volume never gets updated even if the image changes.

In the question you also mention `docker commit`.  Never run this command: it produces an image that can't be reproduced or updated.  It also has some non-intuitive behavior around volumes, which is confusing you in the context of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that we are focusing on different things, as I want to use docker with a persisted /home folder, whereas you're more focusing on the reproducibility, instead of just using it. _the entrypoint script will always overwrite whatever is in the storage whenever the container starts up_, I'm afraid that it is not what I want -- I just want to use docker with a persisted /home folder, and it has to be a docker volume, not host directory, for my specific use case.

Comment: A Docker container only runs a single process; it doesn't have "users" or "home directories" _per se_.  If you expect the content in the image might change and you need the volume to reflect that, your application-specific code needs to merge the changes; there's nothing built into Docker that's capable of doing it.

Comment: Oh, I created a normal unprivileged user in my dockerfile. Anyway, say I just want to use docker with a persisted `/root` folder provided by docker volume, the built-in Docker feature would support that, I suppose.